# Summarize cell values of various columns in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: screenshot of excel]

I want Column A to show:

> Summary
>   black [3XL]*1, black [4XL]*1
>   black [6XL]*3
>   black [2XL]*1

What formulas can I use?

Comment: Sounds like a [SUM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-0761ed42-45aa-4267-a9fc-a88a058c1a57) but I don't know how you are going to get **black [4XL]*2** out of the data from that image.

Answer (score 1):

You could type this formula in A2:

```
=MID(IF(ISBLANK(B2), "", ", " & B$1 & "*" & B2) &
     IF(ISBLANK(C2), "", ", " & C$1 & "*" & C2) & 
     IF(ISBLANK(D2), "", ", " & D$1 & "*" & D2) & 
     IF(ISBLANK(E2), "", ", " & E$1 & "*" & E2) & 
     IF(ISBLANK(F2), "", ", " & F$1 & "*" & F2) & 
     IF(ISBLANK(G2), "", ", " & G$1 & "*" & G2) & 
     IF(ISBLANK(H2), "", ", " & H$1 & "*" & H2) & 
     IF(ISBLANK(I2), "", ", " & I$1 & "*" & I2),  3, 200)
```

... and copy that formula downwards.

Comment: Thank you! I also found another solution (posted as another answer).

Comment: Like I commented to your answer, it uses the same principle, but your solution does not insert the commas like you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Input the following code in A2:

```
=IF(B2,B$1 & "*" & B2 & ", ", "") & IF(C2,C$1 & "*" & C2 & ", ", "") & IF(D2,D$1 & "*" & D2 & ", ", "")...
```

Then drag down.

Comment: It is not comma separated like you asked for. In essence this is the solution I posted 25 minutes ago, but there the commas are correctly inserted.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of the commas. I added the commas to my answer.

Comment: Yes, but now you will have a trailing comma... That is why I have a `MID` in my answer.

Comment: Yes I've noticed that. Thank you for providing the MID code.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted to close the question. NB: also consider the answer of @TomSharpe which allows easy extension to many columns.

Answer (score 0):

Another method if VBA is allowed is to use a ready-made concatenation function like [this one](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/stringconcatenation.aspx) with an array formula:-

```
=StringConcat(",",IF(B2:I2="","",B$1:I$1&"*"&B2:I2))
```

must be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use the following code in A2 and copy downward.
=MID(CONCATENATE(IF(B2<>"",", "&B$1&"*"&B2,""),IF(C2<>"",", "&C$1&"*"&C2,""),IF(D2<>"",", "&D$1&"*"&D2,""),IF(E2<>"",", "&E$1&"*"&E2,""),IF(F2<>"",", "&F$1&"*"&F2,""),IF(G2<>"",", "&G$1&"*"&G2,""),IF(H2<>"",", "&H$1&"*"&H2,""),IF(I2<>"",", "&I$1&"*"&I2,"")),3,1000)